# How to get checkbox value checked and show to input element using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

but the value is only displayed when I click on the checkbox and it does not display the pre-selected values, I want it to show the selected results even if I do not click the checkbox, please correct this code Help me or give me some example code so I can add, thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function thayTheLoai() {
        var huunhan_theloai = [];
        $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function() {
            huunhan_theloai.push($(this).val());
        });
        document.getElementById("input").value = huunhan_theloai.join(", ");
    }
</script>
<label for="default" onclick="thayTheLoai();" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="theloai1" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" ></input>
</label>
<input id="input" type="text"></input>

<script>
    $('#theloai1').prop('checked', true);
</script>
```

This is demo : https://anifast.com/includes/test.php, I want to not need to click the checkbox and still display the checked results

Comment: why don't you juts add `checked="checked"` to the `<input>` element?

Comment: i want create form edit (UPDATE) value selected to MYSQL, i use mysqli_fetch_assoc show input tag because use html data will not exactly

Comment: I don't see anything involving MySQL in the code you attached.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and maybe we can help you.

Comment: If you can help me edit this HTML code, I will add it to my code, please help me add "checked" to the back with javascript because if I use prop ('checked') then the function huunhan_theloai won't work, i don't know how to do it.
My code includes PHP so it will be quite confusing so please help me with HTML

Comment: first: `<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="theloai1" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" ></input>` is not valid HTML. `<input />` is a self closing tag

Comment: This is demo : https://anifast.com/includes/test.php, I want to not need to click the checkbox and still display the checked results

Comment: check the answer and let me know if that helped

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and don't forget to use jquery library.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#theloai1').prop('checked', true);
    var huunhan_theloai = [];
    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function() {
        huunhan_theloai.push($(this).val());
    });
    document.getElementById("input").value = huunhan_theloai.join(", ");
})


function thayTheLoai() {
    if ($('input[name="theloai[]"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $("#input").val(1);
    }else{
        $("#input").val(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what if there are, let's say 3 input elements, each with a different value? your `thayTheLoai()` will update the values to 1 and 0 for each checked fields. This is not good in any way :)

Comment: this is demo link and this code need edit : https://anifast.com/includes/test.php, please help me edit it
code

Comment: You can make it dynamic. Check my new answer. 
That might help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways of doing it:

1. you update the input field from your PHP and MySQL to have the `checked="checked"` on the selected input fields and the run the function on load:

**JS**

```
function thayTheLoai() {
    var huunhan_theloai = [];
    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function() {
        huunhan_theloai.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#input').val( huunhan_theloai.join(", ") );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    thayTheLoai();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="theloai1" onclick="thayTheLoai();" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="theloai1" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" />
</label>
<label for="theloai2" onclick="thayTheLoai();" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="theloai2" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" checked="checked" />
</label>
<input id="input" type="text"/>
```

2. if you want to update the input field using the `$('#theloai1').prop('checked', true);`, you should change it so that it also triggers the `onchanged` event on the input field like this:

`$('#theloai1').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');`

**NOTES**

1. this code is not tested, but it should work
2. make sure you write valid HTML otherwise you might get unexpected results (I fixed your HTML as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="default" class="btn btn-default">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="theloai1" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" ></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="theloai2" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" ></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="theloai3" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" ></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" id="theloai4" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" ></input>

</label>
<input id="input" type="text"></input>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#theloai1').prop('checked', true);
    var huunhan_theloai = [];
    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function() {
        huunhan_theloai.push($(this).val());
    });
    document.getElementById("input").value = huunhan_theloai.join(", ");
})

$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function(){
    checked_id = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            if ($(this).attr("id") != checked_id) {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            }
        })
        $("#input").val($(this).val());
    }else{
        $("#input").val('some default value');
    }
})
```

Comment: also, why set the standard value as `0`? what if that is an option value and it gives unexpected results?

Comment: what if that is an option value and it gives unexpected results?
I did not get this, which option value, can you explain or show.

Or we can use anything instead of 0 if you have some default value

Comment: default value is empty string :) Maybe this is one of the OP cases: `<input type="checkbox" value="0" id="theloai4" class="badgebox" name="theloai[]" />`

Comment: Also, even if you answer a JS only question, you should also let the OP know that there are HTML syntax issues in the code and how you can fix those. That will surely help :)

Comment: If we have empty string as default value, 

We can do this in else section : 
$("#input").val();

That will set value as blank. 

And for this : Also, even if you answer a JS only question, you should also let the OP know that there are HTML syntax issues in the code and how you can fix those. That will surely help :)

I will keep in mind next time. Thanks :)